# With using String instead of Try/Except prevent crashing- How to?

Tags: string, python-3.x, try-except

I am writing a code for the wind chill index for an assignment for college. 
The prof wants us to prevent the code from crashing upon user input of blank or letters, without using Try/Except Blocks.  (He refers to string methods only).

Instead of crashing it should out put an error message eg. ("invalid input, digits only")

I tried utilizing the string.isdigit and string.isnumeric, but it won't accept the negative degrees as integers.

Any suggestions?  (code below)
Would another "if" statement work?

[image: This is the code so far.]

Comment: Maybe remove the `-` before the `.isdigit` ... `userstr.replace('-','').isdigit()`

Comment: You shouldn't really edit the question like that mark it as answered if it is solved, and then pose a new question. If you keep editing and changing what is being asked, it messes up the site. Plus, people don't like "live blogging" your homework and they tend to to down vote.

Comment: What @beroe said. The edit function should be used to clarify your question and add further details. Please don't abuse it to ask a different question. I've rolled back the edit for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the punctuation:

```
if temperature.replace('-','').replace('.','').isnumeric():
```

Comment: Someone down voted my post, so I couldn't ask a separate question...do you think you could answer it??

Answer (score 1):

Use an infinite loop and check that everything seems right.
Whenever there's an error, use the continue statement. And when all checks and conversions are done, use the break statement.

```
import re
import sys
while True:
    print("Temperature")
    s = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip('\n')
    if re.match("^-?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?$", s) is None:
        print("Doesn't look like a number")
        continue
    if '.' in s:
        print("Number will be truncated to integer.")
    temp = int(float(s))
    if not (-50 <= temp <= 5):
        print("Out of range")
        continue
    break
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, but my question specifies without using the Try/Except Blocks.

Comment: Guess it was too speedy.  You can use regular expressions instead of string.isnumeric(). "^-?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?$" should do the trick, it also allows a decimal point.

Comment: I updated my question, to be a little more specific.  It has to not accept non-digits, instead displaying a error message.  Another "if" statement would have to be utilized correct?